# How do I dynamically change which Resource folder I get an image from?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to implement 2 different themes for a WPF Application.  I found this excellent post by @bendewey:
["Can WPF themes be used to include multiple skins for an application that can be changed at runtime?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844388/can-wpf-themes-be-used-to-include-multiple-skins-for-an-application-that-can-be/844652#844652)

And have used it to implement two themes.  I have created two Resource Folders, Lets call them ResourcesTheme1 and ResourcesTheme2 and Two Xaml Resource Dictionary files (Style1.xaml & Style2.xaml) that have the styles.

With this I have been able to set the following styles:
In Style1.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="HomeViewBackGroundImage" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ResourcesTheme1/Background.png" />
</Style>
```

In Style2.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="HomeViewBackGroundImage" TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="/ResourcesTheme2/Background.png" />
</Style>
```

And this has worked a treat for me (if there's a better way please feel free to suggest it).

No the problem I have is that within my mainPage xaml I want to put on a row of buttons and each button has it's own image that it get's from binding to an ObservableCollection.  I would like the Binding to look into the correct resource folder, but don't know how to make it happen without writing code behind.

So what I have is the following Binding:

```
 <Image Name="ContentImage" Source="{Binding ImageName}" Stretch="UniformToFill">
```

And the following code behind:

```
 if (useTheme1)
            {
                imageName = "/PlayingWithThemes;component/ResourcesTheme1/" + imageFileName;
            }
            else
            {
                imageName= "/PlayingWithThemes;component/ResourcesTheme2/" + imageFileName;
            }
```

Any thoughts on how I could make the source for the image something like:

```
Source="ResourceFoler + {Binding ImageName}"
```

Or is there something more generic than:

```
/PlayingWithThemes;component/ResourcesTheme1/"
```

That I could use.

Thanks in advance.

A

Comment: please do a search for `DynamicResource`